# No response while writing my first test for a `Quinn` and `Qp2p` based module

Tags: rust

I have the following code that uses `[QP2P][1]` for network communication.

```
impl Broker {
    pub async fn new(
        config: Config
    ) -> Result<Self, EndpointError> {
        let (main_endpoint, main_incoming, _) = Endpoint::new_peer(
            local_addr(),
            &[],
            config,
        ).await?;

        let mut broker = Self {
            main_endpoint,
            main_incoming
        };

        broker.on_message();

        Ok(broker)
    }

    async fn on_message(&mut self) -> Result<(), RecvError> {
        // loop over incoming connections
        while let Some((connection, mut incoming_messages)) = self.main_incoming.next().await {
            let src = connection.remote_address();

            // loop over incoming messages
            while let Some(bytes) = incoming_messages.next().await? {
                println!("Received from {:?} --> {:?}", src, bytes);
                println!();
            }
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

On the same file I also want to test the above by sending a message and seeing if `on_message` will get it.

```
#[tokio::test]
    async fn basic_usage() -> Result<()> {    
        const MSG_HELLO: &str = "HELLO";

        let config = Config {
            idle_timeout: Duration::from_secs(60 * 60).into(), // 1 hour idle timeout.
            ..Default::default()
        };

        let broker = Broker::new(config.clone(), None).await?;

        let (node, mut incoming_conns, _contact) = Endpoint::new_peer(
            SocketAddr::from((Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST, 0)),
            &[],
            config.clone(),
        ).await?;

        {
            let msg = Bytes::from(MSG_HELLO);
            println!("Sending to {:?} --> {:?}\n", broker.main_endpoint, msg);
            node.connect_to(&broker.main_endpoint.local_addr()).await?.0.send(msg.clone()).await?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
```

What ends happening is that the broker's `println` will not trigger at all. Is me calling `on_message` during initialization and expecting that it will receive messages correct. If not, how can I write the most basic test of checking if a message is received, using `qp2p` endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the frameworks you're using to answer fully, but maybe I can get you pointed in the right direction. I see 2 (likely) issues:

##### Futures don't do anything until polled.

Basically, you call `await` on most of your `async` functions, but you don't ever `await` or `poll()` the `Future` from `on_message()`, so it's basically a no-op and the contents of `on_message()` are never run.

##### I don't think this is structured correctly.

From looking at it, assuming you did `await` the above call, by the time `Broker::new()` finishes in your test, all of `on_message()` would have completed (meaning it wouldn't pick up later messages).

You may wish to spawn a thread for handling incoming messages. There are probably other ways you can do this with futures by adjusting how you poll them. At the least, you probably want to take the call to `on_message()` out of `Broker::new()` and `await` it *after* the message is sent in your code, similar to [how the tests in qp2p are written](https://github.com/maidsafe/qp2p/blob/92e311e22e8d049d411c7e022d8d81527b4880b5/src/tests/common.rs#L37-L68):

```rust
#[tokio::test(flavor = "multi_thread")]
async fn single_message() -> Result<()> {
    let (peer1, mut peer1_incoming_connections, _) = new_endpoint().await?;
    let peer1_addr = peer1.public_addr();

    let (peer2, _, _) = new_endpoint().await?;
    let peer2_addr = peer2.public_addr();

    // Peer 2 connects and sends a message
    let (connection, _) = peer2.connect_to(&peer1_addr).await?;
    let msg_from_peer2 = random_msg(1024);
    connection.send(msg_from_peer2.clone()).await?;

    // Peer 1 gets an incoming connection
    let mut peer1_incoming_messages = if let Ok(Some((connection, incoming))) =
        peer1_incoming_connections.next().timeout().await
    {
        assert_eq!(connection.remote_address(), peer2_addr);
        incoming
    } else {
        bail!("No incoming connection");
    };

    // Peer 2 gets an incoming message
    if let Ok(message) = peer1_incoming_messages.next().timeout().await {
        assert_eq!(message?, Some(msg_from_peer2));
    } else {
        bail!("No incoming message");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I did study qp2p's tests, but I still want to hide away that exact code inside `broker` somehow. Ideally I would like an interface similar to what `zmq` has where the `broker` handles what happens to incoming messages, and not whoever uses it. I will try adjusting the structure according to your suggestion though and see how it works.